# Efficient grouping by 2 columns as a percentage of 3rd

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data in `data.table`:

```
> aru
            tot wk l
     1:  214.31 27 4
     2:  337.10 27 2
     3:  606.00 27 5
     4:  146.80 27 1
     5: 4486.59 27 4
    ---             
579429:  404.00  9 6
579430:  404.00  9 4
579431:  199.90  9 3
579432:  150.00  9 2
579433:  273.00  9 3
```

where:

> "wk" - week of the year
>   "tot" - sales by customer cluster "l" in week "wk".

What I'm trying to achieve is to aggregate sales per week per customer cluster as a percentage of total sales in that week.

So far I've been able to come up with:

**Version 1.**

```
aru[,.(l,tot,Sales_Total=sum(tot)),by="wk"]\
[,.SD[,.(Pct=sum(tot)/unique(Sales_Total))], by="wk,l"]
     wk l         Pct
  1: 27 4 0.348065946
  2: 27 2 0.232702135
  3: 27 5 0.033854772
  4: 27 1 0.249736754
  5: 27 3 0.115843350
 ---                 
212:  9 2 0.396389787
213:  9 5 0.030511998
214:  9 1 0.260533590
215:  9 3 0.130408076
216:  9 4 0.157098738
```

**Version 2**

```
aru[,.(l,tot,Sales_Total=sum(tot)),by="wk"]\
[,.(Pct=sum(tot)/Sales_Total),by="wk,l"][,.SD[1],by="wk,l"]
     wk l         Pct
  1: 27 4 0.348065946
  2: 27 2 0.232702135
  3: 27 5 0.033854772
  4: 27 1 0.249736754
  5: 27 3 0.115843350
 ---                 
212:  9 2 0.396389787
213:  9 5 0.030511998
214:  9 1 0.260533590
215:  9 3 0.130408076
216:  9 4 0.157098738
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient way to achieve the desired outcome with `data.table()` ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may avoid the `.SD` with join i.e. `aru[aru[, .(Sales_Total= sum(tot)), by = wk],  on = 'wk'][, sum(tot)/unique(Sales_Total) ,.(wk, l)]`

Comment: code in the question is not reproducible

Comment: @akrun Yes, it's similar, but as well I think it's more elegant too because it's readable, shorter and thus more transparent. As a bonus, it's as quick as my f5. The person came here and put in effort, why not reward him with extra points?

Comment: No problem.  I know this method, but I was hesitant bcz you consider your own method not that elegant.  It would be better to edit your post that efficiency is also important.  As of now, it is confusing.

Comment: Done. But to be honest I believe elegant code in most cases leads to more efficient code......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard 2-step procedure:

```
aru[, weekly.total := sum(tot), by = wk][, sum(tot) / weekly.total[1], by = .(wk, l)]
```

Comment: Though I already arrived at a similar version, anyway, yours is quickest of the suggested solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table` without the `.SD` would be

```
aru[aru[, .(Sales_Total= sum(tot)), by = wk], on = 'wk'
                  ][, .(Pct= sum(tot)/unique(Sales_Total)) ,.(wk, l)]
```

Or in a compact way with `.EACHI`

```
unique(aru[aru[, .(Sales_Total=sum(tot), l) , wk], .(Pct= sum(tot)/unique(Sales_Total)), 
               on = c("wk", "l"), by = .EACHI])
```

#### data

```
aru <- structure(list(tot = c(214.31, 337.1, 606, 146.8, 4486.59, 404, 
404, 199.9, 150, 273), wk = c(27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L), l = c(4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("tot", 
"wk", "l"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

setDT(aru)
```

Comment: you may have a look at benchmarking different solutions, including yours, in my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

aru <- group_by(aru, wk, l)
aru_summary <- summarise(aru, pct = percent_rank(tot))
```

If I had some of your data to work with I could test it, but essentially this groups your data by week then by 'l', and finds the percent rank for total sales in each group.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarking 4 different solutions, including 2 of @akrun's:

```
f1 <- function(aru) {aru[aru[, .(Sales_Total= sum(tot)), by = wk], on = 'wk'
    ][, .(Pct= sum(tot)/unique(Sales_Total)) ,.(wk, l)]}

f2 <- function(aru) {unique(aru[aru[, .(Sales_Total=sum(tot), l) , wk
    ], .(Pct= sum(tot)/unique(Sales_Total)), on = c("wk", "l"), by = .EACHI])}

f3 <- function(aru) {aru[,.(l,tot,Sales_Total=sum(tot)),by="wk"
                       ][,.(Pct=sum(tot)/unique(Sales_Total)), by="wk,l"]}

f4 <- function(aru) {aru[,Sales_Total:=sum(tot),by="wk"
                       ][,.SD[,.(Pct=sum(tot)/Sales_Total)][1],by="wk,l"]}

f5 <- function(aru) {aru[,Sales_Total:=sum(tot),by="wk"
][,.(Pct=sum(tot)/Sales_Total[1]),by="wk,l"]}

f6 <- function(aru) {aru[, weekly.total := sum(tot), by = wk
][, sum(tot) / weekly.total[1], by = .(wk, l)]}

library(microbenchmark)
aru2 <- copy(aru)
aru3 <- copy(aru)
aru4 <- copy(aru)
aru5 <- copy(aru)
aru6 <- copy(aru)
microbenchmark(f5(aru5), f6(aru6), f3(aru3), f1(aru),f4(aru4),f2(aru2), times=1)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 f5(aru5)   36.34306   36.34306   36.34306   36.34306   36.34306   36.34306     1
 f6(aru6)   36.16731   36.16731   36.16731   36.16731   36.16731   36.16731     1
 f3(aru3)  119.60882  119.60882  119.60882  119.60882  119.60882  119.60882     1
  f1(aru)  120.61820  120.61820  120.61820  120.61820  120.61820  120.61820     1
 f4(aru4)  165.02017  165.02017  165.02017  165.02017  165.02017  165.02017     1
 f2(aru2) 8577.14333 8577.14333 8577.14333 8577.14333 8577.14333 8577.14333     1
```

Comment: Is it based on a bigger dataset?

Comment: @akrun Yes, see the question, it has 500K+ rows. I'm still waiting for a more elegant solution )))

Comment: As far as I know, this can't be made more compact.

Comment: @akrun Thank you for the effort anyway. I appreciate it!